# How can I get multiple references to similar test fixtures

Tags: clojure

I'm creating a fixture to use in my tests. I bind the fixture to a dynamic symbol so that I can refer to it in my tests.

```
(def ^:dynamic *thing-doer* nil)

(defn with-thing-doer
  [config]
  (fn [f]
    (binding [*thing-doer* (create-thing-doer config)]
      (try
        (.start *thing-doer*)
        (f)
        (finally
          (.close *thing-doer*))))))

(use-fixtures :each
  (join-fixtures [(with-thing-doer a-config)]))

(deftest an-example-test
  (do-it! *thing-doer* thing)
  (is (= 1 (count (things-done)))))
```

This works great, but in some tests I need a few of these fixtures, with just slight differences between each. There are enough combinations that I don't want to create a separate dynamic symbol for each and every one. I'd rather that be defined in the test file that's setting up the fixtures. Something like:

```
(defn with-thing-doer
  [doer config]
  (fn [f]
    (binding [doer (create-thing-doer config)]
      (try
        (.start doer)
        (f)
        (finally
          (.close doer))))))

(def ^:dynamic *thing-doer-a* nil)
(def ^:dynamic *thing-doer-b* nil)

(use-fixtures :each
  (join-fixtures [(with-thing-doer *thing-doer-a* a-config)
                  (with-thing-doer *thing-doer-b* b-config)]
```

However it seems that the symbol given to `binding` needs to be known at compile time. Is there a way to do what I want, or a better approach I could take?

Comment: Not the most elegant solution but you could put your fixture data into a map and store it in a dynamic var.

Comment: Have you considered using `with-redefs`?   https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/with-redefs

Comment: @AlanThompson `with-redefs` seems to have the same requirement as `binding` (the symbol given needs to be known at compile time).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [with-bindings](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/with-bindings) to create bindings dynamically. This way bound vars do not need to be known at compile time.

Your `with-thing-doer` function would look like the following:

```
(defn with-thing-doer
  [doer config]
  (assert (var? doer))
  (fn [f]
    (with-bindings {doer (create-thing-doer config)}
      (try
        (.start @doer)
        (f)
      (finally
        (.stop @doer))))))
```

You need to pass the first parameter as a var object.

```
(use-fixtures :each
  (join-fixtures [(with-thing-doer #'*thing-doer-a* a-config)
                  (with-thing-doer #'*thing-doer-b* b-config)]
```